# what is the relation between the api and isEmpty method

Tags: java, android, api

I want to check if the String "registerationId" isImpty :

```
String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "registerationid not found in the prefrences",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return "";

        }
```

but the eclipse give me this error call require API level 9 (Current 8).
I don't understand what the relation between the API and a String method ?
and How suprresLint(New API) effect my project ?
thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some features require a minimum `API` level (because that means that basically they were introduced in *that* API), which must match the one specified in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. If you simply ignore it, you risk that when an user with a lower `API` than the needed installs your app, they'll get unexpected and undesirable effects, like errors, `NullPointerException`s, etc.

It's always recommended to not ignore these alerts and make your minimal `API` according to the functions/methods/functionalities that you use.

Comment: THANK you, I was thinking that API is not related to function in java like the string methods :)

Comment: `String.isEmpty()` is an unusual case, and it seems particularly strange that it wasn't added until API level 9. A good alternative is to use `TextUtils.isEmpty(String)` which checks for null in addition to whether the string is empty (so if you have a string which may be null, you can just make one call rather than `if (string != null && !string.isEmpty())`